# How to run a script shell in google Colab for Swift?

Tags: swift, google-colaboratory

I would like to run a shell command on Colab for Swift. I have tried all the python syntax options, and none work.

I have used the following prefixes:

!

%%

%%shell

Answer (score 3):

Call it via Python

```py
import Python
let shell = Python.import("subprocess").getoutput
prefix func ! (_ command: String) {
  print(shell(command))
}

!"ls -al"
```

Comment: Nice! It's a beautiful solution.